# Can't use map to display score of quiz app in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm getting the issue that I cant do this with the following code:

```
        Question(
          questions[questionIndex]['questionText'].toString(),
        ),
        ...(questions[questionIndex]['answers'] as List<Map<String, Object>>)
            .map((answer) {
          return Answer(() => answerQuestion(answer['score']), answer['text']);
        }).toList()
```

The error says:

```
Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found.
Try removing the extra arguments.
```

Here's my Github project. The error is inside quiz.dart

[My GitHub Project](https://github.com/s3tupw1zard/Quiz-App/tree/development)

thanks

Here's the answer.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:notizapp/quiz.dart';

class Answer extends StatelessWidget {
  final void Function() selectHandler;

  final String answerText;

  Answer(this.selectHandler, this.answerText);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.2,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          primary: Colors.red,
          onPrimary: Colors.white,
        ),
        child: Text(answerText),
        onPressed: selectHandler,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Which line did you get the error

Comment: It's in the line: ```return Answer(() => answerQuestion(answer['score']), answer['text']);```

Comment: Give a complete source code of your Answer Class

Comment: I added it to the post above

Answer (score 1):

There's something wrong with the callback function you pass from `main` to `quiz`.

```
answerQuestion: () => _answerQuestion,
```

You pass along a `VoidCallback`, but what you really need here is to receive an int value from elsewhere in your code, so that you can pass this to your `_answerQuestion` method. This is fixed by changing your answerQuestion to be of type `void Function(int)`; a function that takes an argument of type `int`.

This is done in your `quiz.dart` file.

```
final void Function(int) answerQuestion;
```

Which urges you to change your code in `main.dart` to reflect this change in parameter type.

```
answerQuestion: (int input) => _answerQuestion(input),
```

Lastly, your editor will likely complain about the typing of what you pass to your `Answer` widget, which you can fix by casting the values that you pass along.

```
return Answer(
  () => answerQuestion(answer['score'] as int),
  answer['text'] as String,
);
```

Taking all of the above into consideration, however, I'd urge you to not use a soft-typed Map like you've been using here. Instead, I'd recommend you create a class, which is much easier to work with. I would recommend something like the following:

**Create the classes**

```
class AnswerClass {
  const AnswerClass({
    required this.text,
    required this.score,
  });

  final String text;
  final int score;
}

class QuestionClass {
  const QuestionClass({
    required this.questionText,
    required this.answers,
  });

  final String questionText;
  final List<AnswerClass> answers;
}
```

**Generate your list of questions using the new classes**

```
  final _questions = const [
    QuestionClass(questionText: 'Was ist deine Lieblingsfarbe?', answers: [
      AnswerClass(text: 'Rot', score: 10),
      AnswerClass(text: 'Blau', score: 20),
      AnswerClass(text: 'Gelb', score: 30),
      AnswerClass(text: 'Grun', score: 40),
    ]),
  ];
```

**Change your quiz file to use this new setup**

```
class Quiz extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<QuestionClass> questions;
  final int questionIndex;
  final void Function(int) answerQuestion;

  Quiz({
    required this.questions,
    required this.answerQuestion,
    required this.questionIndex,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Question(
          questions[questionIndex].questionText,
        ),
        ...(questions[questionIndex].answers.map((answer) {
          return Answer(
            () => answerQuestion(answer.score),
            answer.text,
          );
        }).toList()),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Note that now we don't have to cast anything. Typing happens inside the class and it takes away the ability for mistakes during set-up, plus making everything much easier to expand if you want to change things around in the future.

Comment: Thanks for help. I'll try out to use classes instead of maps

Comment: If you need any further help or have some questions, let me know!